# Stored procedure ERROR 1520: File No:ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error when calling it from oracle_cx python driver

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am calling a stored procedure from Python program.

There is an issue that happens on certain values.
For example it fails when i send values `2020`,`2017` but it succeeds wen I send `2010`,`2050` etc. What can be the issue?

DB Version: `NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production`

Oracle_cx: latest

Procedure parameter that causes the issue : `P_FILE_YEAR IN NUMBER`

> Error Message: ERROR 1520: File No:ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large

It fails in the following exception:

```
BEGIN
        SELECT  MAX(mlal_file_no) + 1
        INTO    ln_file_no
        FROM    doc_mail_allocation
        WHERE   mlal_file_year = P_FILE_YEAR
        AND     std_file_type_code = 2 ;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            ln_file_no := 1 ;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            p_error_code := 1 ;
            p_error_msg  := 'ERROR 1520: File No:'||SQLERRM||' AND flal_file_year = '||P_FILE_YEAR;
            RETURN ;
    END ;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the cx_Oracle code you are using.  Show the data values, and how you are binding.  The doc on binding is at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From doc_mail_allocation;

MLAL_FILE_YEAR STD_FILE_TYPE_CODE MLAL_FILE_NO
-------------- ------------------ ------------
          2010                  2          100
          2020                  2          999
```

Your code:

```
SQL> declare
  2    ln_file_no number(3);
  3  begin
  4    SELECT  MAX(mlal_file_no) + 1
  5          INTO    ln_file_no
  6          FROM    doc_mail_allocation
  7          WHERE   mlal_file_year = &P_FILE_YEAR
  8          AND     std_file_type_code = 2 ;
  9    dbms_output.put_line('result = ' || ln_file_no);
 10  end;
 11  /
Enter value for p_file_year: 2010
result = 101

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for p_file_year: 2020
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL>
```

See the difference & error cause? If you declared a variable as "too small" (`number(3)`), for year `2020` `MAX(mlal_file_no) + 1` equals 1000 and it can't fit into such a variable.

Solution? Enlarge `ln_file_no`, or check *why* this happens (if it shouldn't) - then there's error in data.